# JSON.parse(data) return [undefine]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
data = {
  "users": [
    [{
      "value": "01",
      "text": "ABC XYZ"
    }],
    [{
      "value": "02",
      "text": "XYZ ABC"
    }]
  ]
}

var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.users.length; i++) {
  var userlist = jsonData.users[i];
  alert(userlist.text)
}
```

This output: `[undefine];`

But i want to get `[ABC XYZ]` and `[XYZ ABC]`.
So how can I get text or value from this array?

Comment: You already have an `object`...nothing to parse.

Comment: @UdayParmar when you parse JSON you get the data as an array, you're parsing an array which doesn't make sense. I would close this question and Google some JSON tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON response problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183413/parsing-json-response-problem)

Comment: @UdayParmar you have an `object` that contains an `array`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object contains nested array. Try like following.

```js
var data = { "users": [[{ "value": "01", "text": "ABC XYZ" }], [{ "value": "02", "text": "XYZ ABC" }]] };

for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
    var userlist = data.users[i][0];
    alert(userlist.text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` is already a JavaScript object, so no need for the extra `JSON.parse`.

You are getting an `undefined` result because users is an array of arrays, rather than an array of objects.

Try accessing the `userlist` like this:

```
var userlist = data.users[0][i];
```

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/sifoyivayi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: in alert part use alert(userlist[0].text). BDW THANK YOU @Jonathan.Brink

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var data={"users":[[{"value":"01","text":"ABC XYZ"}],[{"value":"02","text":"XYZ ABC"}]]};
for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
var userlist = data.users[0][i];
alert(userlist.text);
}
```